# how to pass the DMAKE and DUSE flags to cmake in a spec file (rpmbuild)

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

A fast question about cmake and spec.

If I compile manually with those commands:

```
export CFLAGS="-O2 -fpic"
  cmake . \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="$CFLAGS" \
 -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING="$CFLAGS" \
 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL="TRUE" \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/man \
 -DSYSCONF_INSTALL_DIR=/etc \
 -DUSE_SSL=1 \
 -DUSE_KRB5=1
make
make install
```

all works fine.
I want to create an rpm, so I edit .spec file to build:

```
%cmake .
make
```

The question is: how to pass the DMAKE and DUSE flags to spec?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
export CFLAGS="-O2 -fpic"
  cmake . \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="$CFLAGS" \
 -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING="$CFLAGS" \
 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL="TRUE" \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/man \
 -DSYSCONF_INSTALL_DIR=/etc \
 -DUSE_SSL=1 \
 -DUSE_KRB5=1
make
make install
```

into this:

```
export CFLAGS="-O2 -fpic"
  %cmake . \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="$CFLAGS" \
 -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING="$CFLAGS" \
 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL="TRUE" \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/man \
 -DSYSCONF_INSTALL_DIR=/etc \
 -DUSE_SSL=1 \
 -DUSE_KRB5=1
make
make install
```

in the spec file.

Using cmake directly (without `%`) works, at least on openSUSE 15.